# Meteor User Accounts: Facebook user sign up / login?

Tags: facebook, meteor, meteor-accounts

I have an app where I want to direct newly signed up users to a welcome page. With the core Meteor users it's easy since there are `Meteor.loginWithPassword` and `Accounts.createUser`. However for signup/login with Facebook there is only `Meteor.loginWithFacebook`.

So is there a way to differentiate between the first time user "logs" in with Facebook and all the other times so I can only direct them to that welcome page once?

Answer (score 0):

[`Accounts.onCreateUser`](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) might be what you're looking for.

You could set a flag in this callback to differentiate new users from regular users.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user.isNew = true;
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```

Then use `Accounts.onLogin` client-side to handle new users being redirected to a welcome page.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(){
  if(Meteor.user().isNew){
    Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),{
      $set:{
        isNew: false
      }
    });
    Router.go("welcome");
  }
});
```

This is untested pseudo-code but you get the idea.